# bind zone transfer between slaves

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I have three dns servers 1) Hidden master that is not accessible to outside. 2) public slave that allowed access from outside. and one tertiary slave that sits on our DR site. Since the master is not accessible to public i want to do zone transfers between the public slave and tertiary slave as the tertiary slave is unable to see the Master. basically zone transfers should be as follows `Master -> Public Slave -> Tertiary Slave` what is the best way to go out doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's name these 3 servers:

```
Hidden Master = ns0
Public Slave  = ns1
DR Slave      = ns2
```

The relationship between ns0 and ns1 is just a "normal" master/slave arrangement.

Configure ns1 to allow transfers from (`allow-transfer`) ns2. You may also need/like to configure ns1 to notify ns2 when the zone changes (`also-notify`)

Comment: on ns2 do i need to set the master as ns1 or ns0 ? or do i leave the configuration as ns1 ?

Comment: ns2 will have no idea that ns0 exists, so you will need to configure ns1 as the `master` for ns2